# Recommendations for a Comprehensive Problem Book(s) in Calculus $3$.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, problem-solving, book-recommendation

I am on the lookout for a comprehensive problem book specifically tailored to Multivariable Calculus and Vector Calculus (Calculus $3$), covering topics such as multiple integrals, partial differentiation, and other advanced concepts of Calculus $3$. While I have found numerous resources for Calculus $1$ and $2$, there seems to be a scarcity when it comes to Multivariable Calculus and Vector Calculus (Calculus $3$) Calculus $3$.

Could anyone recommend a problem book that provides a wide array of problems with varying difficulty levels in Multivariable Calculus and Vector Calculus (Calculus $3$)?

For context I have read:  Stewart's calculus, Thomas' calculus, Larson's Calculus, Baby Rudin and linear algebra by Hoffman and Kunze.

---

EDIT:

There are some good recommendations in the comments, but I am specifically looking for problem books that come with personal endorsements from individuals who have read and worked through them.

---

Thank you in advance for your suggestions!

Comment: Maybe you could purchase Stewart’s multivariable calculus with WebAssign access and do practice problems through WebAssign. It’s a large trove of pretty good exercises.

Comment: @littleO Most of Stewart’s problems involve plugging in numbers into formulas questions, and I have completed most of these problems. Now, I am searching for more advanced problems.

Comment: You might let us know about any other books you've looked at, so we don't waste our time and yours telling you things you already know.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Stewart's calculus, Thomas' calculus, Larson's calculus, and most of Baby Rudin.  The are all the books that I have read, I solve problems randomly from the internet So I need a problem book.

Comment: Maybe https://www.mhprofessional.com/schaum-s-outline-of-advanced-calculus-third-edition-9780071623667-usa – possibly https://www.mhprofessional.com/schaum-s-3-000-solved-problems-in-calculus-9780071635349-usa

Comment: https://personal.math.ubc.ca/~CLP/CLP3/clp_3_mc_problems.pdf looks impressive. Or just type *problems in multivariable calculus* into a search engine to see what comes back.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you for your response! I appreciate your recommendations for problems in multivariable calculus. However, I am specifically looking for problem books that come with personal endorsements from individuals who have read and worked through them. If you have any such books in mind that you’ve found particularly helpful, I would be grateful if you could share them with me.

Comment: I hope you get the personal endorsements you are looking for, but in the mean time you might want to follow up on my suggestions, at least to take a look at them and draw your own conclusions about them.

Comment: There is always ... Schaum's Outline of Advanced Calculus.

Comment: The notes here are good: https://mtaylor.web.unc.edu/notes/

Answer (score 4):

I suggest Theodore Shifrin's *Multivariable Mathematics*, it has a chapter dedicated to the needed linear algebra for multivariable calculus + some good figures and illustrations.

Answer (score 3):

Long time ago, when I was a student, we used “Problems in mathematical analysis” by Demidovich. I think the original book is in Russian, but English translation is available. The book contains a huge number (about four and half thousands) of problems and was so popular that there was written a book of its solutions, called Antidemidovich. The problems are of different hardness. On the one hand, I guess it was a common student problem book, so it should contain a lot of easy problems. But, on the other hand, I was one of the strongest students at our flow and I wanted to pass the exams without attending classes, so the dean of our faculty who taught us analysis, created for me lists of problems from this book to look. The book consists of two chapters, devoted to functions of one and several variables, respectively. So you may look out the second chapter for problems suitable for you.

Comment: I have a pdf version somewhere so I will send it to you when I can.

Comment: @KamalSaleh Thanks, but I still have the book from my student years.

Comment: I mean for the OP's reference. Here's the link: chrome-extension://efaidnbmnnnibpcajpcglclefindmkaj/https://ia902803.us.archive.org/9/items/problemsinmathem031405mbp/problemsinmathem031405mbp.pdf

Comment: @KamalSaleh Thanks. But this version looks rather old, because it contains about 3200 problems whereas my Russian version contains about 4500 problems. Maybe there exists a newer English translation.

Comment: https://ia601002.us.archive.org/31/items/DemidovichEtAlProblemsInMathematicalAnalysisMir1970/Demidovich-et-al-Problems-in-Mathematical-Analysis-Mir-1970.pdf

Comment: @JohnDouma This is the same version as at Kamal Saleh's link.